# Webpack React library to global variable in window

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I use webpack to build React components. 
Here is the JSX file:

```
// index.js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var renderHelloComponnet = function(id) {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <h1>Hello, World!</h1>,
      document.getElementById(id)
    );
}
```

Then, I want to call the function `renderHelloComponnet` in html
I have the config file for webpack:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js'
    },       
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        libraryTarget: "var",
        library: ["ABC"],
    },    
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },    
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.jsx?$/, 
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: { presets:['react'] }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However I can't render my component in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./build/index.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ABC.renderHelloComponnet('example');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the error: `TypeError: ABC.renderHelloComponnet is not a function`

Comment: You need to export the `renderHelloComponent` function somewhere.  Do you have a `module.exports` line at the end of the JSX file?

Comment: @Davin, I set libraryTarget: "var" not 'commonJs', Also, I tried your suggestion: `module.exports.renderHelloComponnet = renderHelloComponnet;` , it doesn't work

Comment: @fudy it should be module.exports = renderHelloComponnet;

Comment: setting `libraryTarget: "var"` means you would need this in your module: `var Library = renderHelloComponnet`.  You *must* set a property named `Library`.

Comment: @DavinTryon , I tried it, still give me empty page and the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you export in your `module.exports` is what you get in your `library` var. So if in your `index.js` you export `renderHelloComponent`:

```
module.exports = renderHelloComponent;
```

then in your `ABC` var you'll get the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ABC('example');
</script>
```

If you want your `library` var to actually have the `renderHelloComponent` method you can export an object with this function inside:

```
module.exports = {
    renderHelloComponent: renderHelloComponent
}
```

Then you will be able to do this:

```
<script>
    ABC.renderHelloComponent('example');
</script>
```